# CoreML MLRecommender issues

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, coreml

I want to create CoreML Recommender model where my training data looks like that:

```
userID (UUID)  | itemID (UUID) | rating (Int)
```

user can rate from 0 to `x` number of items and until every user in training data rates same number of items (for example 10) everything works fine.

But when I try to create traiing model where:

- user1 rates two items,
- user2 rates five items,
- user3 rates one item

I start having this error:

```
Playground execution terminated: An error was thrown and was not caught:
▿ Item IDs in the recommender model must be numbered 0, 1, ..., num_items - 1.
  ▿ generic : 1 element
    - reason : "Item IDs in the recommender model must be numbered 0, 1, ..., num_items - 1."
```

how can I fix this?

full playground code:

```
let trainingData = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/.../test.csv"))
let model = try MLRecommender (trainingData: trainingData, userColumn: "userID", itemColumn: "itemID", ratingColumn: "rating")
let recs = try model.recommendations(fromUsers: ["050510A3-0C96-4F57-8A45-433422680464"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue by using normalisation and dummy scores that are greater than 0. More info here: https://pawel.madej.com/post/ml-recommender-in-practice